# Differential equations with initial condition in Python (change a working code)

Tags: python, differential-equations

I am pretty new in Python. I have a working code which looks like

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.integrate as sp
import sys
g, l, k = 9.81, 10, float(input())
PTS = 6
def rhs( y, t, g, l, k ): return [ k*t/l * np.cos(y[1]) - g/l * np.sin(y[1]),y[0] ]
y0 = [ 0, 0 ]
t = np.linspace( 0, 6, PTS+1 )
y = sp.odeint( rhs, y0, t, args = (g, l, k) )
for i in range(PTS): print( t[i], np.arctan(k*t[i]/g) *180/np.pi )
```

where you have to write a value **0.5** (it is value of "k").
The output of this code is:

time **value of y**
0.0  **0.0**
1.0 **2.91774937823**
2.0 **5.82044363971**
3.0 **8.69348861202**
4.0 **11.5231772897**
5.0 **14.297051396**

Now I want to use a value in time t = 5 (**y = 14.297051396**) as my initial condition and find values of y in time t = 6, ..., 16 for  **k=1.1**. How should I change my code?

I tried this code

```
   import numpy as np
   import scipy.integrate as sp
   import sys
   g, l, k = 9.81, 10, float(input())
   PTS = 12
   def rhs( y, t, g, l, k ): return [ k*t/l * np.cos(y[1]) - g/l * np.sin(y[1]), y[0] ]
   y0 = [ 14.297051396, 5 ]
   t = np.linspace( 5, 17, PTS+1 )
   y = sp.odeint( rhs, y0, t, args = (g, l, k) )
   for i in range(PTS): print( t[i], np.arctan(k*t[i]/g) *180/np.pi )
```

and write **1.1**, but the output is the same as in the case that I write y0 = [ 0, 0 ].

What did I do wrong? Could somebody **explain to me**, how to change it? (I am self-learner in python and I do not study programming).

Comment: Your modified code seems to work fine for me. I get the following output.`5.0 29.27727419991014
6.0 33.93199056194524
7.0 38.12884190338944
8.0 41.89349697838171
9.0 45.261622745694794
10.0 48.27284019198932
11.0 50.96680364220253
12.0 53.38093962579151
13.0 55.54933261036378
14.0 57.502334254714036
15.0 59.26659245272294
16.0 60.865300623818555`

Comment: I agree, the code works as desired.